# Filtrar no where a maior data com LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, linq, expressões-lambda

Como eu passo no where dessa linq a max datatransacao, ou seja, desejo trazer o resultado mas pela maior data.

```
var resultado = (from ci in webDB.T_Controle_Importacao
                             where ci.CNPJ == cnpj
                             let dd = EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, ci.DataTransacao)
                             select dd >= 45 ? 3
                                  : dd >= 15 ? 2
                                  : 1).Take(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode ordenar a query de forma que o objeto com a maior data apareça na frente, e depois pegar o primeiro registro:

```
var resultado = (from ci in webDB.T_Controle_Importacao
                                 .OrderByDescending(ci => ci.DataTransacao)
                 where ci.CNPJ == cnpj
                 let dd = EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, ci.DataTransacao)
                 select dd >= 45 ? 3
                      : dd >= 15 ? 2
                      :            1
                )
                .Take(1);
```

Note que ao fazer isso, **é recomendável que você tenha um índice na coluna que armazena a data no banco de dados**, de forma que a ordenação não fique lenta demais.

Answer (score 2):

Ordene para trazer a maior data com `orderby` **campo** `descending`

```
var resultado = (from ci in webDB.T_Controle_Importacao
                    where ci.CNPJ == cnpj
                    let dd = EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, ci.DataTransacao)
                    orderby ci.DataTransacao descending
                    select dd >= 45 ? 3 : dd >= 15 ? 2 : 1).Take(1);
```